# Compiling Boost example projects with Cygwin + gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, cygwin

While trying to compile the boost asio example project 
    async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

I get errors like the following:

```
__MSABI_LONG was not declared in this file scope
BOOST_ASIO_NATIVE_ERROR(ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE)

__MSABI_LONG was not declared in this file scope
BOOST_ASIO_NATIVE_ERROR(ERROR_OPERATION ABORTED)
```

This is with Boost 1.55.0 and gcc version 4.8.3

boost was compiled with gcc and the following commands

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 cxxflags="-D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501
./b2 install
```

I attempted to compile the sample project with

```
gcc -std=C++11 -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -I C:\boost_1_55_0 C:\boost_1_55_0\boost\asio.hpp async_tcp_echo_server.cpp
```

Comment: Which `gcc` are you using in with the last command? Normally you wouldn't use Windows style pathnames with Cygwin's compiler.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "which gcc" g++ will be invoked here, as boost is a C++ library. I am running gcc on the windows command prompt with the $path environment variables set accordingly. I have tried using the cygwin command prompt too, which generates identical errors.

Comment: There's a native Windows port of of GCC called MinGW. Since your using native pathnames, I was wondering you weren't accidentally using the wrong `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of old thread.
I managed to fix it by reinstalling the boost lib via Cygwin setup_x86.exe.
The version I installed is 1.57. And you don't have to put -D option in the command line.
Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

1_57 version from cygwin setup doesn't help for me, it gives me `fd_set errors`.

This is what I tried to make the boost example code work:

1. add `#define __MSABI_LONG(x) x` at the top. - chilly, I know :)
2. add these flags to `g++`:`-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -std=c++11 -lboost_system -lws2_32`

Voila!

Comment: this is 1_58 boost btw.