# Boost ASIO example does not build

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to do the fist asio [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer1.html).  I am using Boost 1.60, CLion 1.2 and Cygwin.

**With this C++ code:**

```
    //
    // timer.cpp
    // ~~~~~~~~~
    //
    // Copyright (c) 2003-2015 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
    //
    // Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
    // file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
    //

    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/asio.hpp>
    #include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

    int main()
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io;

        boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
        t.wait();

        std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

**And this CMake file:**

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
    project(Test1)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
    #add_compile_options(-D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -lboost_system -lws2_32)
    add_compile_options(-D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501)



    set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "D:\\Downloads\\boost_1_60_0\\boost_1_60_0")

    find_package(Boost)
    if (Boost_FOUND)
        include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    endif ()


    set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
    add_executable(Test1 ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

**I get the following error:**

```
error: '__MSABI_LONG' was not declared in this scope        BOOST_ASIO_NATIVE_ERROR(ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE)
```

This error repeats a number of times over different macros.

So using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115192/compiling-boost-example-projects-with-cygwin-gcc), the code is changed to:

**C++**

```
    //
    // timer.cpp
    // ~~~~~~~~~
    //
    // Copyright (c) 2003-2015 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
    //
    // Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
    // file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
    //
    #define __MSABI_LONG(x)

    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/asio.hpp>
    #include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

    int main()
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io;

        boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
        t.wait();

        std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

**CMake**

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
    project(Test1)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
    add_compile_options(-D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -lboost_system -lws2_32)



    set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "D:\\Downloads\\boost_1_60_0\\boost_1_60_0")

    find_package(Boost)
    if (Boost_FOUND)
        include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    endif ()


    set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
    add_executable(Test1 ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

**I get the following error**

```
error: expected primary-expression before ',' token BOOST_ASIO_NATIVE_ERROR(EPIPE))
```

I get this one a number of times as well.

***Edit 1***

**If I change the code to be:**

```
    //
    // timer.cpp
    // ~~~~~~~~~
    //
    // Copyright (c) 2003-2015 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
    //
    // Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
    // file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
    //
    #define __MSABI_LONG(x) x

    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/asio.hpp>
    #include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

    int main()
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io;

        boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
        t.wait();

        std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

**Sample of error output:**

```
    D:/Downloads/boost_1_60_0/boost_1_60_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:36:44: error: cannot convert 'long int*' to 'volatile int*' for argument '1' to 'int _InterlockedIncrement(volatile int*)'
       if (::InterlockedIncrement(&d.init_count_) == 1)
                                                ^
    D:/Downloads/boost_1_60_0/boost_1_60_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:40:45: error: cannot convert 'long int*' to 'volatile int*' for argument '1' to 'int _InterlockedExchange(volatile int*, int)'
         ::InterlockedExchange(&d.result_, result);
                                                 ^
    D:/Downloads/boost_1_60_0/boost_1_60_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp: In static member function 'static void boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::manual_startup(boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data&)':

       if (::InterlockedIncrement(&d.init_count_) == 1)
                                                ^
    D:/Downloads/boost_1_60_0/boost_1_60_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:48:40: error: cannot convert 'long int*' to 'volatile int*' for argument '1' to 'int _InterlockedExchange(volatile int*, int)'
         ::InterlockedExchange(&d.result_, 0);
```

***EDIT 2***

**Change the CMake code to specify the correct OS in the compiler option yields this:**

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
    project(Test1)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
    add_compile_options(-D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00 -lboost_system -lws2_32)



    set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "D:\\AdrianMattocks\\Downloads\\boost_1_60_0\\boost_1_60_0")

    find_package(Boost)
    if (Boost_FOUND)
        include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    endif ()


    set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
    add_executable(Test1 ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

**I get this error (this is just a sample due to SO size limits but these errors are repeated many times):**

```
    D:/Malachi/Downloads/boost_1_60_0/boost_1_60_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp: In static member function 'static void boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::startup(boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data&, unsigned char, unsigned char)':
    D:/Malachi/Downloads/boost_1_60_0/boost_1_60_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:36:44: error: [Kno matching function for call to '_InterlockedIncrement(long int*)'
       if (::InterlockedIncrement(&d.init_count_) == 1)
    D:/Malachi/Downloads/boost_1_60_0/boost_1_60_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:36:44: error: invalid conversion from 'long int*' to 'volatile long unsigned int*' [-fpermissive]
       if (::InterlockedIncrement(&d.init_count_) == 1)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Look again at the answer (it's incorrectly highlighted). `__MSABI_LONG(x) x`. I have no idea if that would make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  Missed the 'x'.  :-|

Comment: How about not defining anything like `__USE_W32_SOCKETS` and `_WIN32_WINNT` and just using the defaults?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  I get the following error:
error: #error You must add -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS to your compiler options.

Comment: For those finding this later, I never got this to build with CLion, so I went back to Visual Studio 2015 and it worked just fine.  Maybe it was a DLL compilation thing, maybe it was me, I don't know and since Visual Studio works it wasn't worth the effort figure it out.

Comment: I came across this issue on AppVeyor after their February update involving msys2. Somehow cmake now thinks it is on cygwin. I wonder what was before. I recall I didn't have to supply `__USE_W32_SOCKETS` and now it asks.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem as well, and managed to get rid of the `'__MSABI_LONG' was not declared in this scope` and similar errors when trying to compile *Boost ASIO*. I had downloaded Boost separately by following the Boost library documentation. The process to fix the error was quite straightforward:

- Delete any references to the Boost libraries in the compiler's path and include options.
- Run the [Cygwin installer](https://www.cygwin.com/) and delete any previous occurrence of the Boost libraries.
- Re-run the Cygwin installer and install Boost libraries from the installer (you can search for Boost and selectively install all the packages you're interested in).
- Restart your IDE.

Therefore, Boost was "handled" by Cygwin, and I did not have any more errors when compiling again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you helped me so much!:) thanks for start my C++ boost journey